# How to set DataGridView's Height properties if the control is inside a ToolStripControlHost? C# WINFORMS

Tags: c#

I have a TextBox that will show a DataGridView within a contextMenuStrip everytime the user presses the F1  key. I used ToolStripControlHost to host the dataGridView inside the contextMenuStrip. Please consider my code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.F1)
    {
        dataGridView1.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
        dataGridview1.Height = 30;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; // some DataTable with 50+ rows,..or greater.

        ToolStripControlHost tsHost = new ToolStripControlHost(dataGridView1);
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(tsHost);

        contextMenuStrip1.Show(textBox1, 0, 27);
    }
}
```

My problem is I can't set programmatically the height of the dataGridView when it's already added in the contextMenuStrip as an item. Since I can't set the height of the grid, the tendency is it adjusts its height depending on the size of its dataSource.

I'm missing something in my code? Please help.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured it out. I just added this code:

```
ToolStripControlHost tsHost = new ToolStripControlHost(dataGridView1);
tsHost.AutoSize = false; // Set AutoSize property to false.
tsHost.Height = 30;      // then set Height property value.
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(tsHost);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change height of your dataGridView1 directly because it's inside other controls - therefore it's height is limited by the size of it's parent controls. If you want to change it's height, you should instead change the heights of contextMenuStrip1 and tsHost. I prefer doing it like this:

```
dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tsHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
contextMenuStrip1.Height = 30;
```

If it doesn't work, try finding contextMenuStrip1's parent controls and change their heights.